# Do I need reference to mscoree.dll assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, dllregistration, delay-sign

I have found [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mscorsn.StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx) nice article while trying to **find Delay signed assembly programmatically.**

But, the program in the above link is using **StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx** class which is available in **mscoree.dll** assembly, I guess.

But, I couldn't find reference to mscoree.dll anywhere inside my Visual studio.

Where can I get reference to mscoree.dll?

One more point, in the above link why reference to mscorsn is given? Which does actually I need mscorsn.dll or mscoree.dll?

Comment: It's PInvoke, so you don't need to add any reference.

Comment: Then, what is the solution? My program could not recognize StrongNameSignagureVerificationEx class.

Comment: Go back to a textbook and learn what is PInvoke (platform invoke). Then you will see why you don't need a class called `StrongNameSignagureVerificationEx` at all.